# many to many relationship - save in multiple database column and retrieve

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, store

I have many to many relationships of cart and drycleaning.

In model drycleaning :

```
public function carts()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\cart');
  }
```

and in model cart :

```
 public function drycleanings()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\drycleaning');
    }
```

And in view file I am accepting checkbox values as  : drycleaning_id[] and input values as q_drycleaning_id[]

```
@foreach($drycleaning as $drycleaning)
    <div class="checkbox" ><label><input type="checkbox" name="drycleaning_id[]" value="{{$drycleaning->id}}">{{$drycleaning->name}}</label></div>
    <input type="text"  name="q_drycleaning_id[]"  placeholder=" {{$drycleaning->name}} Quantity">
 @endforeach
```

I save values to cart_drycleaning database table

Saving of drycleaning_id which are taken by checkbox from view by

```
$cart->drycleanings()->attach($request->drycleaning_id);
```

To retrieve the data I used

```
  $drycleaning = drycleaning::whereHas('carts',
       function($query) use($cart_id) {
          $query->where('carts.id', $cart_id);
      })->get();
```

Please help me to save input values of q_drycleaning_id[] to the same table i.e. cart_drycleaning. and also to retrieve it to view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the carts to the current cart, `$cart->carts->sync(q_drycleaning_id)`

Comment: I am not sure how